# Switch icon on mouse hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying one of the Twitter Bootstrap provided icons in an anchor. I want the default icon to be switched to icon-white when i have the mouse over the anchor.

The effect should be like when you hover over the anchors in the navbar [here](http://angularjs.org/)

How is this done?

Answer (score 4):

You use the CSS pseudo-class :hover to set a different background:

```
.menulink:hover { background-image: url('alternative_sprite.png'); }
```

Comment: Swedish as well. If you don't mind feel free to login to twitter-bootstrap and write to "wingy" there. (Kul med svenska kontakter) :)

Comment: **note:** It should be `background-image: url('alternative_sprite.png');` The answer as given by Anders will actually override the `background-position` (at least in FF).

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery toggleClass() on hover to change the icon to white.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g7HC/83/).
HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<a href="#"><div class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-print"></i>&nbsp;Click</div></a>
<br/>
```

Script:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("a").hover(function(){
        $('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-envelope glyphicon-print');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

just switch over the glyphicons image?

(extracted from my css, which is a sass version, and my images are in a different place, but you get the idea...)

```
&:hover{
  i{
    background-image: url("../images/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the AngularJS website uses a webfont to display icons:

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
```

And they insert the font-icon using CSS pseudo-class :before:

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Which it is a brilliant solution, if you resolve to [create your own icon web font](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/).

Or even better, you can use [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS psuedo-class :hover..

```
.menulink:hover { background-image: url('myimage.png'); }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Twitter at all, it's common CSS stuff.

Comment: Regarding my answer, dont you have to use background-image and not just background as the above answer?

Comment: Nope. But I guess some would consider it cleaner. I wouldn't.

Comment: But Twitter Bootstrap is using spriting. Isn't the answer above not compatible with Bootstrap? Basically the image I need to switch to is done by adding a class "icon-white".

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answer above are not working and give a background image with all glyphicons at ones.

This works form me. Notice that I have changed the color of the icons to fits my needs.

```css
a:hover > [class^="icon-"] {
    background-image: url("bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-orange-dark.png") !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already a few quick solutions posted that will do the trick. I would like to add my solution if you would like to achieve this without using JQuery or CSS:

1. Crate an `$scope` object that contains the name of the icon class your would like to set by default.

   ```
   $scope.myClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
   ```
2. Add `ng-class` directive and get the class name from `$scope.MyClass`, add `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave` directives and change `$scope.MyClass` value

   ```
   <span
        ng-class="myClass"
        ng-mouseover="myClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'"
        ng-mouseleave="myClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok'">
   </span>
   ```